# Why does using pipes with `who` cause mom not to like me?

Tags: c, linux

In a program I'm writing, I `fork()` and `execl()` do determine `who mom likes`. I noticed that if I set up pipes to write to `who`'s stdin, it produces no output. If I don't set up pipes to write to stdin, then `who` produces output as normal. (yes, I know, writing to `who`'s stdin is pointless; it was residual code from executing other processes that made me discover this).

Investigating this, I wrote this simple program (**edit: for a simpler example, just run:** `true | who mom likes`):

**`$ cat t.c`:**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    int stdin_pipe[2];
    assert( pipe(stdin_pipe)                  ==  0);
    assert( dup2(stdin_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO) != -1);
    assert( close(stdin_pipe[0])              ==  0);
    assert( close(stdin_pipe[1])              ==  0);

    execl("/usr/bin/who", "/usr/bin/who", "mom", "likes", (char*)NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running results in no output, which is what surprised me initially:

```
$ cc t.c
$ ./a.out
$
```

However, if I compile with `-DNDEBUG` (to remove the piping work in the `assert()`s) and run, it works:

```
$ cc -DNDEBUG t.c
$ ./a.out
batman pts/0        2014-08-15 12:57 (:0)
$
```

As soon as I call `dup2(stdin_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO)`, `who` stops producing output. The only explanation I could come up with is that `dup2` affects the tty, and `who` uses the tty do determine who I am (given the `-m` flag prints "only hostname and user associated with stdin"). My main question is:

Why can't `who mom likes`/`who am i`/`who -m` determine who I am when I give it a pipe for stdin? What mechanism is it using to determine its information, and why does using a pipe ruin this mechanism? I know it's using `stdin` somehow, but I don't understand exactly how or exactly why `stdin` being a pipe matters.

Comment: Using strace show that `ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0xbef0743c) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)` fails without -DNDEBUG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/who.c;h=f07cee61c8e6c64b1ecc8f92773fc3c0fffbff02;hb=HEAD#l575) for GNU coreutils who:

```
if (my_line_only)
 {
   ttyname_b = ttyname (STDIN_FILENO);
   if (!ttyname_b)
     return;
   if (STRNCMP_LIT (ttyname_b, DEV_DIR_WITH_TRAILING_SLASH) == 0)
     ttyname_b += DEV_DIR_LEN;       /* Discard /dev/ prefix.  */
 }
```

When `-m` (my_line_only) is used, `who` finds the tty device connected to stdin, and then proceeds to finds the entry for that tty in `utmp`.

When `stdin` is not a terminal, there is no name to look up in `utmp`, so it exits without printing anything.

Comment: Ah, nice! I tried googling "who source linux" but just came up with results for `source`. Thanks!